# Summing 3D matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, 3d

I have a 3D matrix, "xx", with dimensions: 6847x2x2. Here is one slice:

```
         > xx[1,,]
              [,1] [,2]
         [1,]  0.4  0.1
         [2,]  0.1  0.4
```

And another...

```
          > xx[6847,,]
                [,1] [,2]
           [1,]  0.4  0.9
           [2,]  0.1  0.8
```

What I want to do is create one 2x2 matrix where that matrix is the sum of all 6847 matrices. That is,  matrix_new[1,1] would reference .4+..+.4 and matrix_new[1,2] would be .1+..+.9      Thanks

Comment: Hmm...none seem to get the result. With the first post, I get a 6847x2 with yours. @Nicola, I do get a 2x2 matrix, but all the values are na.

Comment: Based on the example `xx <- array(c(0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5), dim=c(3,2,2));  apply(xx,c(2,3), FUN=sum)` there is no NA.  If you have `NA` values as elements, you may need to add `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: If you have `NA`s, try: `apply(xx, c(2,3), FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks you guys. na.rm was correct. I used both your apply functions as well as colsums, and both got the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colSums` (or `rowSums`) may be useful here

```
# Data 
ar <- 1:12
dim(ar) <- c(3, 2, 2)

ar[1,,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    7
#[2,]    4   10

 ar[2,,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    8
#[2,]    5   11

ar[3,,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    9
#[2,]    6   12

 # Sum over first dimension
 colSums(ar, dims=1)
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    6   24
 #[2,]   15   33
```